# Rails ajax authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hello guys I am developing an application in ruby on rails I am trying save the contents of a form through ajax 
Here is the code of my form :

```
<%= form_for([@question, @question.answers.build],remote: true) do|f|%>
       <h2>Link</h2>
      <%= f.text_field :link ,:id=>'link'%>
        <h2>Time</h2>
      <p class="s-line">
         <%= f.label :hh,"HH:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :hh ,:id=>'hh'%>
        <%= f.label :mm,"MM:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :mm,:id=>'mm' %>
        <%= f.label  :ss,"SS:"%>
        <%= f.text_field :ss,:id=>'ss'  %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user,:value =>session[:username] %>
      </p>

      <%= f.submit "Answer" ,:class=>'btn btn-medium btn-success'%>

<% end %>
```

and the code of controller is :

```
def create
    question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer  = question.answers.create(ans_params)
    respond_to do |create|
      create.js{}
    end
  end
```

an I was getting this error :

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

And I tried to solve this by putting this line

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

to my controller.
now I am getting this error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

In this line

```
respond_to do |create|
```

Please help

Comment: Don't skip the authenticity token verification! Why would you do that?? Have you included the `csrf_meta_tags` in your application layout? Do you have more code and a full error with backtrace we can see?

Comment: I have csrf_meta_tags  in my layout file

Comment: If you are doing Ajax, you also need to make sure the csrf token is sent with your requests. Check out your Ajax requests and make sure you have csrf token and a correct request format.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution lies here:

```
<%= form_for([@question, @question.answers.build],remote: true) do|f|%>
```

---

**Question**

Why are you sending `@question.answers.build` with the `@question` var? IMO this is bad practice, and I'd do this:

```
<%= form_for @answer, remote: true do |f| %>
```

---

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
   resources :answers, only: [:new, :create]
end

#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
respond_to :html, :js: json
before_action :find_question, only: [:new, :create]

def new
    @answer = @question.answers.build
end

def create
    @answer = @question.answer.create(ans_params)
end

private

def find_question
     @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
end

def ans_params
   params.require(:answer).permit(:attrs)
end
```

For your Ajax authentication issue - I believe it is a problem with how you're declaring & handling the data in your form. I would try the refactors I posted above & see if that helps